# AICc for small sample sizes

Tags: information-theory

I'm selecting models using the information theoretic approach. I've just read that the AICc should be used to rank candidate models where the number of parameters in a model reaches 30% of the sample size. Is this a good benchmark to use when deciding to use AIC or AICc?

Comment: It would be good to mention/give a link to where you read that.  I believe Burnham and Anderson recommend AICc for `N-k<40`, but I don't have their book handy.

Answer (score 5):

Burnham and Anderson (see [online pdf](http://ecologia.ib.usp.br/bie5782/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=bie5782:pdfs:burnham_anderson2002.pdf)) recommend using AICc when the ratio n/K is small. In particular, they suggest to use AICc when n/K < 40. In other words, once the number of parameters reach 2% or 3% of the amount of data, you should prefer AICc.